# Command Still Executes Despite Cancel Button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button the executes a user form to display with a required password before executing the buttons command, however when the user form is displaying it freezes the rest of the sheet. On the user Form a I created a cancel button so that the user can exit out of the UserForm should he not know the password and use the other buttons I have on the sheet. When the user clicks the cancel button, it still executes the command even though he/she did not put a password in. The user Form works properly when you enter the correct password/incorrect password, its only when you click cancel that it does not work. Could any on please offer any help? see my code below for the button and the code for my cancel button

```
Sub Feeder_Schedule()

UserForm1.Show

If Sheets("Bulk_Data").Visible = xlVeryHidden Then
    Sheets("Bulk_Data").Visible = True
    End If

Sheets("Bulk_Data").Select

Sheets("Home").Visible = xlVeryHidden


End Sub
```

code for the Cancel button

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Unload Me


End Sub
```

Comment: I do not see any code where you check if the user clicked ok or cancel or whatsoever. The code after/below Userform1.show will run as soon as you dismiss the form. And never ever put an Unload into a userform.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it right change/add to your code of the userform

```
Option Explicit
' USERFORM CODE
Private m_Cancelled As Boolean

' Returns the cancelled value to the calling procedure
Public Property Get Cancelled() As Variant
    Cancelled = m_Cancelled
End Property

Private Sub buttonCancel_Click()
    ' Hide the Userform and set cancelled to true
    Hide
    m_Cancelled = True
End Sub


' Handle user clicking on the X button
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer _
                                  , CloseMode As Integer)

    ' Prevent the form being unloaded
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then Cancel = True

    ' Hide the Userform and set cancelled to true
    Hide
    m_Cancelled = True

End Sub
```

Your code could then look like that

```
Sub Feeder_Schedule()

Dim frm As UserForm1
    Set frm = New UserForm1

    frm.Show

    If Not frm.Cancelled Then

        If Sheets("Bulk_Data").Visible = xlVeryHidden Then
            Sheets("Bulk_Data").Visible = True
        End If

        Sheets("Bulk_Data").Select

        Sheets("Home").Visible = xlVeryHidden

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Was just about to post almost exactly the same code.This is deffo the way to go... +1

Comment: Yeah probably a better solution

Comment: Sad thing is that there was a time when we could've pointed OP in the direction of all the great SO documentation on userforms. Would be a great complement to this answer

Comment: I received a Run-time error 2147418105 " Automation error The callee (server[not server application])is not available and disappeared; all connecctions are invalid. The call may have been executed."

Comment: As mentioned in one of my comments you should not use Unload in the code of the form. This is usually the root cause for the error you mentioned. Just replace every Unload with a Hide